# MySQLi Not returning all rows?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a query as follows

```
SELECT s.`uid` FROM `sessions` s
```

(this was an extended query with a LEFT JOIN but to debug i removed that join)

FYI the full query was

```
SELECT s.`uid`, u.`username`, u.`email` FROM `sessions` s LEFT JOIN `users` u ON s.`uid`=u.`user_id`
```

There are three results in the sessions table, for ease sake i'll just list the uid

```
| UID |
|  0  |
|  0  |
|  1  |
```

when i execute the above query, i would expect to receive all 3 rows. In phpMyAdmin, i do. in PHP, i do not, i only receive the rows with 0 as the UID. However, in php. the $result->num_rows is 2, not 3. This is my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT s.`uid` FROM `sessions` s";
$result = $acpDB->query($sql);
$staffList = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($data = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        var_dump($data);
        $staffList[] = array(
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried plain ->query($sql), and also the prepare/execute method, neither seem to work.

The only conflict i can think of, is that i already pull that row from my session class, but how can i just get it to return all rows, even rows that have already been pulled from that table in another class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Dan

Comment: By the way, isn't 'u' in the uid stands for 'unique'?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I thought that was a name for the table, so that left joins etc can be easily done. But the same issue arises with the top query statement. If i remove the s from the other one i still get the same results.

Comment: I asked about u, not s. but from your other comment I already learned that this field has no unique index

Comment: Ohhh i see, no it means user in my case, so user id

Comment: it is just impossible, I am sure you're modifying the data somewhere before the `select` you're just not paying attention to it. Maybe a function that has a delete in it and you forgot. at your place I would recheck my code line by line...

Comment: Yeah i see it, i added in tons of debug and its calling a session destroy before the page processes which i do not want it to do

Comment: Yeah all sorted, thanks, i never thought the session would destroy on a regenerate_id, i thought it only updated the id

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the ways PHP and phpmyadmin fetch the data.
Strictly speaking, phpmyadmin consists of just the same PHP code.

So, there is nothing to look for in the code. The problem apparently in the data structure/joins/whatever else you omitted.

Another usual reason is different databases you are connecting to.

Comment: http://i.gyazo.com/c1d24ff2436b51461084d43c047cd8c4.png

This any help? The same query returns two different results, phpMyAdmin returns all of them, PHP returns all but the one returned earlier from the sessions script (runs before the code i put above), i think it must be to do with that but i dont know how to solve it

Comment: this code returns ALL the rows from the table. Means there are only two rows. either you deleted one row or querying different database or watching results wrong way. None of these issues are programming-related.

Comment: it should return all of the rows, but it doesnt. The results in the database do not get changed until the very end of the page runtime, so it must be programming related somehow

Answer (score 0):

I had a session_regenerate_id(true); in my session class, which caused it to remove the values for just enough time that the other query didnt find the results. adding in a force read and force write of the session fixed this issue.